# How can I draw my database design?

Tags: mysql, database

I have mysql database and I want a software which can draw the database design for me?

is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can use MySQL Workbench, it's supposed to have reverse engineering (from database to model).

http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/

Comment: +1  Yes, this is the tool for diagramming database schema.  Currently MySQL Workbench can reverse-engineer an SQL script, but not a live database.  But it's easy to save any database schema as an SQL script with `mysqldump --no-data`

Comment: I'm pretty sure next version will have option to do forward and reverse engineering on live database. I've seen it in one of the Alpha releases.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/), it's free and next release (currently alpha) will be major step forward (it will replace MySQL Query Browser).

You can do reverse engineering with [Visual Architect](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/dbva/) or [Power Designer](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner) but you have to pay.

Answer (score 1):

Toad for Mysql also does a pretty good job.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the Oskar answer.

Here is the link: [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.fr/products/workbench/features.html)

And some screenshots:

[image: workbench visual design]
<sub>(source: [mysql.fr](http://www.mysql.fr/common/images/products/workbench_visual_design.gif))</sub>
[image: workbench change management]
<sub>(source: [mysql.fr](http://www.mysql.fr/common/images/products/workbench_change_management.gif))</sub>

By the way i don't think the reverse engineering feature is available in the free version..

You can also take a look at those ones:

- [SQLyog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLyog)
- [Navicat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navicat)
- [HeidiSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeidiSQL)

Comment: DBDesigner is no longer in development. In fact MySQL workbench is it's successor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) Schema Designer tool.

It is very simple and intuitive to use. One can create visual DB design from existing Database in just 3 clicks;

1. Select Database,
2. Right Click on canvas to choose tables,
3. Click on OK (as all tables are selected by default)

It is worth giving a try... Hope it helps...

[image: SQLyog's Schema Designer tool screenshot]